# Are all characters equal-width in a monospace font?

Tags: fonts

Given:

```
|==============================|
|     MARKET                   |
|                              |
|                wow           |
|               O              |
| look at      /|\             |
| my thing     / \      so     |
|   O__▣               O cool  |
|  /|         such    /|\      |
|  / \       O thing  / \      |
|           /|\                |
|           / \                |
|                              |
|==============================|
```

Source: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/457130/63734

Why does the `▣` cause issues for the spacing?

---

**Update**

I now realize this might be local to my Windows 7 computer.

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Internet Explorer:

[image]

Comment: That character doesn't cause issues here (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/irf64.png). If you are seeing issues it's more likely that the font it's being rendered in doesn't have that character so is being replaced with a different font.

Comment: @Cai Hmm, that could be it. See my update with web browser screenshots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied the original text from the link and pasted it in InDesign, defining **Andale Mono** as a font .

Activating the **Hidden Characters** I discover there's a different character than a regular space in the middle:

[image: hidden characters]

It is a **Sixth Space**,  probably put there because the square character does not belong to the font as @Cai said in his comment.

[image]

Replacing the **Sixth Space** for a **Regular Space**, the issue disappears, even without having the special character at the font:

[image: Issue]

If you have not InDesign, use an Online Hidden Characters Viewer like http://show-hidden-characters.dostring.com/

Here the result:

[image: online]

Comment: very strange... that sixth space absolutely isn't there when I copy/paste the text in the question

Comment: @Cai Did you try in InDesign? Not all the programs show all the Hidden Characters, Word and Illustrator doesn't show the Sixth Space, just a blank space.

Comment: I did (I did try Illustrator first but I did then try InDesign when it didn't show in AI). Maybe it's a browser or OS thing and something is stripping it from the text before I copy it.

Comment: I add an online hidden characters result at the answer

Comment: It doesn't show there either! Either by browser or OS must be stripping it from the text